# break for nested loops without executing sub-sequential code

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to figure out How I can break a nested for loop to achieve the following:

1. When it breaks out the nested for loop, it's still inside the outer for loop
2. When it breaks out the nested for loop, it doesn't execute the remaining code anymore, in this case, the last line.

```
def for_loop_flow():
    for a in range(0, 2):
        print "a = %s" % a
        for b in range(3, 5):
            print "b = %s" % b
            if b == 4:
                print "XXXXXXXXbreak"
                break
        print("big piece of logic here, when nested for loop breaks, I "
              "don't wanna be here")
```

For now, I can only think of using a flag:

```
def for_loop_flow():
    for a in range(0, 2):
        print "a = %s" % a
        flag = True
        for b in range(3, 5):
            print "b = %s" % b
            if b == 4:
                print "XXXXXXXXbreak"
                flag = False
                break
        if flag == True:
            print("big piece of logic here, when nested for loop breaks, I "
                  "don't wanna be here")
```

Any better way doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any `for` loop with a `break` and a flag variable can be expressed as a `for` with an `else` clause. So in your case, you can get rid of the flag and use:

```
for a in range(2):
    print "a = {:d}".format(a)
    for b in range(3, 5):
        print "b = {:d}".format(b)
        if b == 4:
            print "BREAK!"
            break
    else:
        print "Only run if no break in inner loop"
```

Note that this also works with `while`:

```
while check_if_still_true():
    do_work()
    if shall_we_break():
        break
else:
    we_exited_because_check_returned_false()
```

Comment: always good to know something python has while java doesn't :)